# R - Sum rows of same category

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Observation=c("A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  Type=c(1,2,2,1,1,1,2), Value= c(1.5,1,3,2.1,3,4,6))
```

I want to sum the rows of each Observation that has the same Type of data(1 or 2), so it looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame (Observation=c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
                 Type=c(1,2,1,1,2), Value= c(1.5,4,2.1,7,6))
```

I´ve looked thoroughly for related question but couldn´t fnd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> aggregate(Value~Type+Observation,df1,sum)
  Type Observation Value
1    1           A   1.5
2    1           B   2.1
3    2           B   4.0
4    1           C   7.0
5    2           C   6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(Value=sum(Value, na.rm=TRUE)), by=list(Observation, Type)]
#    Observation Type Value
#1:           A    1   1.5
#2:           B    2   4.0
#3:           B    1   2.1
#4:           C    1   7.0
#5:           C    2   6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Observation, Type) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```